# Scope not defined c++ need int inout

Tags: c++, scope, int, printf, scanf

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("Hello, CS 101! \n");

   int age{
     printf("How old are you? \n")
    };
   printf("OK, you are",scanf(%i,&age),"years old.");


   return 0;
}
```

Our assignment needs to use scanf and printf to find out how old the user is, then to print a statement stating how old they are.

Our professor didn't go over syntax and gave us the code in class, but I was too far from the board to see. This is what I got on my own, but I have not found good coding resources for c++.

I get the error scope not defined, can someone help me. Also, if anyone has good resources for learning from scratch that would be great. This is my first time coding, thanks.

Comment: Are you learning C or C++?

Comment: age should be a function or variable?

Comment: You want to learn from scratch because of the position of your seat?  Please, have a talk with your professor about this problem.  Also, C is not C++ is not C, and you're writing C.

Comment: _@Botan_ _"but I have not found good coding resources for c++"_ Seriously? What about your textbook?

Answer (score 2):

I fixed your code. Hope it is what you are after:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
   printf("Hello, CS 101! \n");


   // declare age as int
   int age;

   // ask for age 
   printf("How old are you? \n");

   // get user input into age
   scanf("%d", &age);

   // display entered age
   printf("OK, you are %d years old.\n", age);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Considering OP is a beginner, this would be a lot better if you explained your changes.

Comment: @Borgleader I added comments, explaining what is happening.